# Color handling in Python

Tags: python, colors

For my clustering gui, I am currently using random colors for the clusters, since I won't know before hand how many clusters I will end up with.

In Python, this looks like:

```
import random
def randomColor():
    return (random.random(),random.random(),random.random())
```

However, when I update things, the colors change.

So what I would favor is to have a function which has an input argument I such as

```
def nonrandomColor(i):
   ...
   return color
```

would always return the same color for the same I, while keeping the ability to generate arbitrarily many colors.

Answer does not have to be formulated in Python, it's more the general layout I'm interested in.

Comment: Clearly what you want is a three-dimensional generalization of the urinal protocol http://blog.xkcd.com/2009/09/02/urinal-protocol-vulnerability/ , preferably in HSL space so you can put bounds on saturation and lightness to guarantee a decent amount of contrast.   ...or maybe I'm overthinking it.

Comment: In the spirit of overthinking, using [sub-random sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-discrepancy_sequence) for colors should provide some contrast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the [seed](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.seed) of the random generator to the index, this might be cheaper than storing the colors.

```
random.seed(i)
```

Note that this will make random numbers *way* less random than before. If that is a problem, e.g. if your application uses random numbers elsewhere, you might want to look into the caching options suggested by other answers.

Comment: -1 because frequently setting your random seed causes your random number generator to be highly non-random. This would be a bad idea if your program also uses random numbers for anything else.

Comment: One way to avoid messing with your random number generator is to use a specialised one for the colors. `color_rnd = random.Random(); color_rnd.seed(i)`

Answer (score 6):

One way is to use caching. Use a `defaultdict`:

```
>>> import random
>>> def randomColor():
...    return (random.random(),random.random(),random.random())
... 
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> colors = defaultdict(randomColor)
>>> colors[3]
(0.10726172906719755, 0.97327604757295705, 0.58935794305308264)
>>> colors[1]
(0.48991106537516382, 0.77039712435566876, 0.73707003166893892)
>>> colors[3]
(0.10726172906719755, 0.97327604757295705, 0.58935794305308264)
```

Comment: Setting the first few entries of the dict to easily distinguishable colors (red, yellow, green, blue) up front will decrease your chance of producing a graph with lines in blue, blue, blue, and blue.

Comment: @Jason: your idea is useful. The risk of the colors being various shades of blue is not high, but having the first few colors static also makes the graph more understandable.

Answer (score 1):

You want to store the colors in a dictionary or a list:

```
colors = {} # int -> color
def nonrandomColor(i):
   if i not in colors:
      colors[i] = randomColor()
   return colors[i]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want repeatable non colliding colors then you could use something like the function below.  It sections the number into 1, 10, 100 and then uses them as the RGB parts of the color.

```
def color(i):
  r = i % 10
  g = (i//10) % 10
  b = (i//100) % 10
  return(r*25, g*25, b*25)
```

For example:

```
color(1) == (25,0,0)
color(10) == (0,25,0)
color(999) = (225,225,255)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `i` to seed the random number generator. So, as long as the seed remains the same, you get the same value.

```
>>> import random
>>> random.seed(12)
>>> random.randint(0,255), random.randint(0,255), random.randint(0,255)
(121, 168, 170)
>>> random.seed(12)
>>> random.randint(0,255), random.randint(0,255), random.randint(0,255)
(121, 168, 170)
>>> random.seed(10)
>>> random.randint(0,255), random.randint(0,255), random.randint(0,255)
(146, 109, 147)
>>> random.seed(10)
>>> random.randint(0,255), random.randint(0,255), random.randint(0,255)
(146, 109, 147)
```

Depending on the number of colours you're likely to generate (i.e., 10 or a million), the caching method might be better than the `seed()` method.

Comment: Do not mess with the global seed if possible! Create your own `random.Random` object and set its seed instead.