# Should I use `random.seed` or `numpy.random.seed` to control random number generation in `scikit-learn`?

Tags: python, numpy, random, scikit-learn, random-seed

I'm using scikit-learn and numpy and I want to set the global seed so that my work is reproducible.

Should I use `numpy.random.seed` or `random.seed`?

From the link in the comments, I understand that they are different, and that the numpy version is not thread-safe. I want to know specifically which one to use to create IPython notebooks for data analysis. Some of the algorithms from scikit-learn involve generating random numbers, and I want to be sure that the notebook shows the same results on every run.

Comment: for using `np.random.seed()` you won't need to import anything, but for using `random.seed()` you will  need to import the `random` module

Comment: Please DO NOT set the global seed, this is unsafe. You can create your own `Random` object and set its seed instead. Read the last comment by  Muhammad Alkarouri in this question for a safer workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3717456/1524913

Comment: @Leb thanks for the link, but it's not clear which one I should use in my case. I edited the question.

Comment: @JeromeJ it's not clear how to use `color_rnd` as per that example. If I run `color_rnd.seed(1234)`, will functions like `sklearn.cross_validation.KFold` "know" to use it instead of whatever RNG it normally uses?

Comment: They may not if they rely on `random` directly sadly. My point was, at least then. whenever you type code, avoid to use `random` itself directly. I'm not sure what to do in your scenario, that's a bit of a bummer. Maybe a decorator but I think you'd have to tinker with the function context but I'm not 100% sure, I'd have to have a deeper look at it to be sure.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

> Should I use np.random.seed or random.seed?

That depends on whether in your code you are using numpy's random number generator or the one in `random`.

The random number generators in `numpy.random` and `random` have totally separate internal states, so `numpy.random.seed()` will not affect the random sequences produced by `random.random()`, and likewise `random.seed()` will not affect `numpy.random.randn()` etc. If you are using both `random` and `numpy.random` in your code then you will need to separately set the seeds for both.

### Update

Your question seems to be specifically about scikit-learn's random number generators. As far as I can tell, scikit-learn uses `numpy.random` throughout, so you should use `np.random.seed()` rather than `random.seed()`.

One important caveat is that `np.random` is not threadsafe - if you set a global seed, then launch several subprocesses and generate random numbers within them using `np.random`, each subprocess will inherit the RNG state from its parent, meaning that you will get identical random variates in each subprocess. The usual way around this problem is to pass a different seed (or `numpy.random.Random` instance) to each subprocess, such that each one has a separate local RNG state.

Since some parts of scikit-learn can run in parallel using joblib, you will see that some classes and functions have an option to pass either a seed or an `np.random.RandomState` instance (e.g. the `random_state=` parameter to [`sklearn.decomposition.MiniBatchSparsePCA`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.MiniBatchSparsePCA.html#sklearn.decomposition.MiniBatchSparsePCA)). I tend to use a single global seed for a script, then generate new random seeds based on the global seed for any parallel functions.

Comment: I'm using `numpy.random` for any random number generation I do in the console. I don't know what `sklearn` uses internally. Hence my question.

Comment: Thanks. One reason I'm asking is because the only way to pass a `numpy.random.RandomState` instance to `sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV` is by explicitly passing an object to its `cv` argument, like `sklearn.cross_validation.StratifiedKFold`. However that constructor requires you to know the number of rows in your data set when the model is instantiated. That means you have to re-instantiate the model whenever you want to fit it on new data, which is not how you're supposed to use these objects. I'll ask a targeted follow-up

Comment: I'm not sure I really understand your motivation. Is there some particular reason why you *want* the cross-validation folds to be different for different search parameters in `GridSearchCV`? As far as I can see it should not matter.

Comment: That's not what I mean. I want the folds to be the same every time I open the notebook and press "Run all", because I need the results to be reproducible.

Comment: OK, in which case couldn't you just create a new `cv` instance (either using the same global seed, or some new random seed derived from it) every time you want to fit on some new data?

Comment: I was hoping to avoid that. But I just demo'ed it, and having to create a new instance to fit new data might actually be a feature and not a bug. "Explicit is better than implicit" etc.

Comment: As a general principle I think it's best to keep any kind of meta-optimization code separate from model classes. Not only is it more explicit, but it also tends to lead to more reusable code.