# Different importance features and aoc when using class weights

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, decision-tree

I'm using scikit learn with the code shown below.

I have class imbalance (roughly a 90:10 split of class 0:1). After reading a number of other questions I've used the class_weighted parameter.

However every time I run the code I get a different set of important features and different AOC, precision, recall etc.

The problem is not there when I remove the class_weight parameter.

As shown, I've set the random_state to be constant so this is not the issue. A good number of the predictors are highly correlated. Does anyone know what the issue is? (Note I posted a similar question yesterday but this was downvoted as I hadn't been clear enough so rather than have a long chain of comments I've deleted the question which is hopefully clearer to others and now provides the information needed).

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y)

parameters = {
    'max_depth': [6,7, 8],
    'min_samples_split': [100, 150],
    'min_samples_leaf': [50,75]
    }

clf = GridSearchCV(DecisionTreeClassifier(
    random_state=99,
    class_weight='balanced'), 
    parameters, refit=True, cv=10) 

clf.fit(x_train, y_train.ravel()

# create main tree using best settings
clf2 = DecisionTreeClassifier(
    max_depth=clf.best_params_['max_depth'],
    min_samples_split=clf.best_params_['min_samples_split'],
    min_samples_leaf=clf.best_params_['min_samples_leaf'],
    random_state=99,
    class_weight='balanced')

clf2.fit(x_train, y_train.ravel())
```

Comment: As I also said in the previous (now deleted) question. Setting a random_state at only one place will not make the code a duplicateble one. You need to check the splitting.

Comment: `train_test_split` also uses random shuffling to shuffle the data and then split. So thats one place of randomness. Then GridSearchCV will also have randomness due to `cv` param.

Comment: Arh I see now what you mean! yes you are correct - thank you. As I said, I'm new to all this and didn't know that could be the cause of the problem. Marked as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the above code, there are multiple points of randomness.

1) `train_test_split` uses random shuffling to shuffle the data and then split into train and test. So first you need to stabilize that.

2) GridSearchCV uses a `cv` parameter, which for classification tasks uses a StratifiedKFold() to split the data into different folds. So that's also randomness there.

**Workaround**: Please set this line in your code before processing the data (Better if on top, just below the import lines).

```
numpy.random.seed(SOME_INTEGER)
```

Use `numpy` or `np` as you have imported.

Explanation: Please see the below questions:-

- [Should I use `random.seed` or `numpy.random.seed` to control random number generation in `scikit-learn`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31057197/should-i-use-random-seed-or-numpy-random-seed-to-control-random-number-gener)
- [How to seed the random number generator for scikit-learn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40750394/how-to-seed-the-random-number-generator-for-scikit-learn)