# Python - Are calls to functions of numpy.random thread safe?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-random

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31057197/should-i-use-random-seed-or-numpy-random-seed-to-control-random-number-gener), it isn't. But this has not been consistend with what I've observed so far. Consider the following script:

```
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool
from queue import Queue

SIZE=1000000
np.random.seed(1)
tPool = Pool(100)
q1 = Queue()

def worker_thread(i):
    q1.put(np.random.choice(100, 5))

tPool.map(worker_thread, range(SIZE))

q2 = Queue()
np.random.seed(1)
for i in range(SIZE):
    q2.put(np.random.choice(100, 5))

n = 0
for i in range(SIZE):
    n += (q1.get() == (q2.get()))

print(n)
```

Basically what I'm testing here is if *SIZE* number of calls will generate the same sequence in the multi-threaded environment as in the single-threaded environment. For me this will output n=SIZE. Of course this could be just chance, so I ran it a few times and been having consistent results. So my question is, are calls to functions of the numpy.random package thread-safe?

Answer (score 2):

I've run your script several times on my machine and got arrays of `999995`, `999992` nearly as often as `1000000` (python 3.5.2, numpy 1.13.3). So the answer you're referring to is correct: `np.random` *may* produce a different result in multi-threaded environment.

You can see it yourself if you increase the pool size, say to `1000`, and sample size, say to `50`. I was able to achieve 100% inconsistency even for a smaller `SIZE=100000`.

Comment: Hmm, this is weird. I've tested it on three different machines, running python 3.5.2 and numpy 1.13.3 and I always get consistent results, even after increasing the threadpool to 1000, increasing the sample size to 50 and the range of sampling to 10'000. How can this be?

Comment: Interesting. I'll try it on a different machine too. Looks like native implementation really matter here. Right now I'm using Linux, x86_64, kernel 4.10.0-37-generic.

Comment: @BananaCode I can confirm that `np.random` is indeed stable on my other machine. Tried python 3.5.2 and 3.6.0, numpy 1.13.3 and 1.12.1. This makes me think that it depends on `libc` or even kernel version. But still thread safety is not guaranteed.

Comment: Thanks for testing @Maxim. However due to your first experiment, I have migrated my code to using np.random.RandomState, which is supposedly thread-safe.