# RandomizedSearchCV best_params_ changes everytime when I run this program

Tags: scikit-learn

I want to use `LogisticRegression` to classify. So, I use `RandomizedSearchCV` to pick best C params in `LogisticRegression`.

My question is: Why do `best_params_` change every time I run this program? I assume that `best_params_` should always stay the same.

Code as follows:

```
data = load_iris().data
target = load_iris().target

# DATA Split

TrainData , TestData ,TrainTarget , TestTarget = train_test_split(data,target,test_size=0.25,random_state=0)
assert len(TrainData)==len(TrainTarget)
Skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5)

#Model

LR = LogisticRegression(C=10,multi_class='multinomial',penalty='l2',solver='sag',max_iter=10000,random_state=0)

#Params selection with Cross Validation
params = {'C':np.random.randint(1,10,10)}
RS = RandomizedSearchCV(LR,params,return_train_score=True,error_score=0,random_state=0)

RS.fit(TrainData,TrainTarget)

Result = pd.DataFrame(RS.cv_results_)
print RS.best_params_
```

Comment: Please put your code inside code block.

Answer (score 2):

You are correctly setting the random_state to LogisticRegression and RandomizedSearchCV. But there's one more source which can change the train test data and thats when you generate the `params` using `np.random`. This is changed on each run.

For controlling this behaviour, you can set the `numpy.random.seed()` to an integer of your choice. Something like this on top of your code:

```
np.random.seed(0)
```

**Note**: Doing this will also set seed for all scikit modules, because internally scikit uses this. So you may not need to set random_state everywhere in that case, but its not recommended.

See this answer - [Should I use `random.seed` or `numpy.random.seed` to control random number generation in `scikit-learn`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31057197/should-i-use-random-seed-or-numpy-random-seed-to-control-random-number-gener).

You may want to check these resources also:

- [What does numpy.random.seed(0) do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21494489/what-does-numpy-random-seed0-do)
- [Random seed on SVM sklearn produces different results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47923258/random-seed-on-svm-sklearn-produces-different-results)
- [How to seed the random number generator for scikit-learn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40750394/how-to-seed-the-random-number-generator-for-scikit-learn)
- [How do I set a random_state for an entire execution?](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/faq.html#how-do-i-set-a-random-state-for-an-entire-execution)

Comment: @Kumar  Thanks. you are right.  I should use np.arange(1,11,1) to get list ,instead  np.random.randint(1,10,10)